# How to lock editing log messages after commiting the change?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have used below command to update the log message for particular revision. Now everybody able to change the log messages for every revision. how to revert this back to restriction to update the log messages.

```
$ svnadmin setlog "path" -r 7 --bypass-hooks message.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done anything else on your repository you are fine. You used the **svnadmin** command which is only usable directly on your server. So nobody with remote-only access can modify the repository in the same way.

Usually you can enable to edit log messages remotely by creating a **pre-revprop-change**-hook (which returns 0) inside the hooks directory of your repository. Then everybody could change your log messages(not advisable).

In standard configuration SVN forbids this kind of modification.

Comment: Before this change, if i wanted to do any change it usually shows error, but now it is not showing any error and i am able to change the log message. Now i want to revert this. It should not accept modification of log messages.

Comment: how did you do the changes _before_ usually you omit the "--bypass-hooks" command switch which is exactly what I was talking about.